# What's the name of this romance/ecchi manga about a girl who becomes the landlord of a boy's house?

Tags: maison-ikkoku

There's a manga I remember I read and liked, but I can't remember the name! It is about a girl who takes over a house as some kind of landlord and the boy starts to like her right away. There is also a girl who dresses like a prostitute in the house. They all throw a party in this boy's room to celebrate the girl who is the landlord, but he gets angry because he is studying. There is also an ecchi scene where this landlord is repairing the bathroom and he comes in and yeah, so on... does anyone know the name of this manga?

Comment: Sounds a bit like this one: Kanojo no Kagi wo Akeru Houhou

Comment: I agree with @nhahtdh

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Sounds like [Maison Ikkoku](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1453/Maison_Ikkoku):

> The story takes place in Maison Ikkoku, a worn and aging boarding house where Godai Yuusaku, a 20 year old college applicant, lives. Though honest and good-natured, he is weak willed and often taken advantage of by the offbeat and mischievous tenants who live with him. As he is about to move out, he is stopped at the door by the young and beautiful Otonashi Kyouko, who announces she will be taking over as landlord. Godai immediately falls in love with her and decides to stay.

I personally never read the manga, but in the anime the residents always throw parties in Godai's room, especially when he's trying to study.

More info:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maison_Ikkoku)
- [ANN](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=376)
- [Wikia](http://maisonikkoku.wikia.com/)